# Why is my if statement not comparing strings properly?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I'm writing code for a program that asks the user for their telephone number. It goes through multiple conditionals until a valid number format is given. One of the conditions is that the first 3 digits of the input must be between 200 and 999. The problem is I'm pretty sure I'm writing it correctly, but I have no idea why it's not 'tripping' the condition when I put an invalid number in. Like, say, '127-444-9870'. All the other conditions are tripping. I thought maybe I just couldn't compare strings in this way, but when I ran it in the console, it worked properly. To test I put num1 = '1' and num2 = '3' and then ran num1 < num2 which returned 'true'. So, I think what I'm doing is possible.

Here's my code so far:

```
number = ''
while number.lower() != 'q':
    number = input('Enter phone number or q to quit: ')
    numnums = number.split('-')
    if number.lower() == 'q':
        break
    elif number.count('-') != 2:
        print('Phone number should have 2 dashes.')

    elif not numnums[0].isdigit() or len(numnums[0]) != 3:
        print('First part of phone number must be a 3-digit number.')

    elif not numnums[1].isdigit() or len(numnums[1]) != 3:
        print('Second part of phone number must be a 3-digit number.')

    elif not numnums[2].isdigit() or len(numnums[2]) != 4:
        print('Last part of phone number must be a 4-digit number.')

    elif '200' > numnums[0] > '999':
        print('first 3 digits must be between 200 and 999')

    else:
        number = number.replace('-', '.')
        print(f'Phone number with dashes replaced: {number}')
```

Comment: It's your `if` condition.  `if '200' > numnums[0] > '999':` says "if numnums[0] is less than 200 AND numnums[0] is greater than 999", which is of course impossible.  You should write `if not ('200' <= numnums[0] <= '999'):`.

Comment: I urge you to use a library rather than parsing phone numbers on your own. Try Google's [phonenumbers](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/).

Comment: Thank you but this is a school assignment and I haven't gotten to using libraries yet

Comment: @Code_monkey Can you accept one of the answers below if either solves your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong operator. `>` is greater than, and `<` is less than. You code says: "if `numnums[0]` is less than 200 and `numnums[0]` is greater than 999, then do this code". Instead, you want it to say: "if `numnums[0]` is greater than 200 and `numnums[0]` is less than 999". Just change this line:

```
elif '200' > numnums[0] > '999':
```

to

```
elif '200' < numnums[0] < '999':
```

You may also want to consider changing these types from strings to numbers. It will make your code more readable. Like this:

```
elif 200 < int(numnums[0]) < 999:
```

However, this doesn't change the output of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes here:

```
elif '200' > numnums[0] > '999'
```

1. The logic doesn't make sense because there are no numbers smaller than 200 and larger than 900.
2. You're comparing strings (numnums[0] is a string) while your logic requires comparing numbers.

It should be something like

```
elif 999 > int(numnums[0]) > 200
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You're right and wrong. Your comment made me realize that I should be using 'or' instead of 'and' so your first point is correct. Your second one is wrong though you can compare numbers if they are strings. After changing '

Comment: The second point is still important.  You happen to be getting a correct result either way because the string and number order between 200 and 999 is the same. But if instead of 999 it was 1000, you would get an error because '1000' < '200'.